# 13.04 desktop is incomplete - top bar disappears and no side bar

Tags: unity

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I followed the install steps perfectly but every time I log into my user account the desktop that appears is incomplete. The top bar disappears and there is no side bar. I can access the settings by right clicking and editing my desktop but I have no idea what to do. Can someone tell me if there is a fix for this?

I am using a dell dimension 2400

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting unity to fix any errors. Unfortunately the old way to reset unity was disabled in 13.04, so you'll need to install a package.

If you can make it to your desktop, press Ctrl-Alt-t to open a terminal window. Then install the unity-reset package by typing the following

```
wget "https://launchpad.net/~amith/+archive/ubuntutools/+build/3910667/+files/unity-reset_0.1-8_all.deb"
sudo dpkg -i unity-reset_0.1-8_all.deb
```

Then type:

```
unity-reset
```

After a moment your panel and launcher should appear.

Comment: Sorry, That didn't help. I followed your instructions and it stated after the last one that it was Unable To Locate Package Unity-Reset.

Comment: Updated instructions to download directly, give it a try now.